# getting unspecified error in windows phone using sqlce database

Tags: windows-phone-7, listbox, sql-server-ce

I have a table named "dic" in my sqlCe database which is a dictionary database. it have two columns named english,bangla.
I have a textbox and a search button.By using this button and textbox i can search word, matched with english column and entered text. Now I want to show the TOP 5 result matched with english column and entered text into a listbox. In the listbox first row will show the data of "english" column and the 2nd row will contain the data of "bangla" column from the search result.Thus the listbox will contain total 5*2=10 row.
I tried something very initial but gets error:

```
 condrokotha_newContext db = null;

    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();


        db = new condrokotha_newContext(condrokotha_newContext.ConnectionString);

        //db.Dispose();
        db.CreateIfNotExists();
        db.LogDebug = true;

    }


 private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        if (db!=null)
        {

            var contacts = (from m in db.Dics where m.English.Contains(@"abandon") select m.English);
            List<string> listBoxItems = new List<string>();
            string s;

            try{

            foreach (var a in contacts)
            {
                s = a;
                listBoxItems.Add(s);

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex){ MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString()); }

            listBox1.ItemsSource = listBoxItems;
        }           
    }
```

It gets an exception "Unsoecified error".

How can i do what i want????

N:B: My code for using database is given below.

```
#pragma warning disable 1591
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated by a tool.
//     Runtime Version:4.0.30319.18010
//
//     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
//     the code is regenerated.
 // </auto-generated>
 //------------------------------------------------------------------------------

 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.ComponentModel;
 using System.Data;
 using System.Data.Linq;
 using System.Data.Linq.Mapping;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Linq.Expressions;
 using System.Reflection;


using System.IO;
using System.IO.IsolatedStorage;
using Microsoft.Phone.Data.Linq.Mapping;
using Microsoft.Phone.Data.Linq;


public class DebugWriter : TextWriter
{
private const int DefaultBufferSize = 256;
private System.Text.StringBuilder _buffer;

public DebugWriter()
{
    BufferSize = 256;
    _buffer = new System.Text.StringBuilder(BufferSize);
  }

public int BufferSize
{
    get;
    private set;
}

public override System.Text.Encoding Encoding
{
    get { return System.Text.Encoding.UTF8; }
}

#region StreamWriter Overrides
public override void Write(char value)
{
    _buffer.Append(value);
    if (_buffer.Length >= BufferSize)
        Flush();
}

public override void WriteLine(string value)
{
    Flush();

    using(var reader = new StringReader(value))
    {
        string line; 
        while( null != (line = reader.ReadLine()))
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(line);
    }
}

protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if (disposing)
        Flush();
}

public override void Flush()
{
    if (_buffer.Length > 0)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(_buffer);
        _buffer.Clear();
    }
}
#endregion
}


public partial class condrokotha_newContext : System.Data.Linq.DataContext
{

public bool CreateIfNotExists()
{
    bool created = false;
    using (var db = new condrokotha_newContext(condrokotha_newContext.ConnectionString))
    {
        if (!db.DatabaseExists())
        {
            string[] names = this.GetType().Assembly.GetManifestResourceNames();
            string name = names.Where(n => n.EndsWith(FileName)).FirstOrDefault();
            if (name != null)
            {
                using (Stream resourceStream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(name))
                {
                    if (resourceStream != null)
                    {
                        using (IsolatedStorageFile myIsolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
                        {
                            using (IsolatedStorageFileStream fileStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(FileName, FileMode.Create, myIsolatedStorage))
                            {
                                using (BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(fileStream))
                                {
                                    long length = resourceStream.Length;
                                    byte[] buffer = new byte[32];
                                    int readCount = 0;
                                    using (BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(resourceStream))
                                    {
                                        // read file in chunks in order to reduce memory consumption and increase performance
                                        while (readCount < length)
                                        {
                                            int actual = reader.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                                            readCount += actual;
                                            writer.Write(buffer, 0, actual);
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        created = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        db.CreateDatabase();
                        created = true;
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                db.CreateDatabase();
                created = true;
            }
        }
    }
    return created;
}

public bool LogDebug
{
    set
    {
        if (value)
        {
            this.Log = new DebugWriter();
        }
    }
}

public static string ConnectionString = "Data Source=isostore:/condrokotha_new.sdf";

public static string ConnectionStringReadOnly = "Data Source=appdata:/condrokotha_new.sdf;File Mode=Read Only;";

public static string FileName = "condrokotha_new.sdf";

public condrokotha_newContext(string connectionString) : base(connectionString)
{
    OnCreated();
}

#region Extensibility Method Definitions
partial void OnCreated();
#endregion

public System.Data.Linq.Table<Dic> Dics
{
    get
    {
        return this.GetTable<Dic>();
    }
}
}

   [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.TableAttribute(Name="dic")]
 public partial class Dic
{

private string _English;

private string _Bangla;

public Dic()
{
}

[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Name="english", Storage="_English", DbType="NVarChar(1000)")]
public string English
{
    get
    {
        return this._English;
    }
    set
    {
        if ((this._English != value))
        {
            this._English = value;
        }
    }
}

[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Name="bangla", Storage="_Bangla", DbType="NText", UpdateCheck=UpdateCheck.Never)]
public string Bangla
{
    get
    {
        return this._Bangla;
    }
    set
    {
        if ((this._Bangla != value))
        {
            this._Bangla = value;
        }
    }
}
 }
#pragma warning restore 1591
```

Comment: Where is the database located? Can you share a CREATE TABLE script?

Comment: You did not answer any of my questions. Do you include the database file with your app, then run CreateIfNotExtists, before accessing the database.

Comment: Yes i included my database file in my app and also i run CreateIfNotExtists. I mention it on my update code.  @ErikEJ

Comment: It could be the Locale of your database that is not supported on the device, feel free to email me a repro project, and I will have a look

Comment: Please check the link. I uploaded the whole demo project here.  https://www.dropbox.com/sm/create/PhoneApp1.rar   @ErikEJ

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/4vpwggvvrgf3unm/PhoneApp1.rar @ErikEJ

Comment: Does the list shows?? why doesn't work on my pc?? And finally how to reach my goal which i mentioned in my question?? @ErikEJ

Comment: Yes, the list shows, and I do not know why is does not work on your PC

Comment: I used windows phone7,VS 2010 in win 7. What about u?? @ErikEJ

Comment: Same, but Windows 8.1